# How to include in the result of a `SELECT ... GROUP BY ...` all the other columns that are functionally dependent on the grouping ones?

Tags: primary-key, group-by, aggregate, dependencies

I'll base this question on a toy example.

Let this be table `A`:

```
            A
-------------------------
 U | V | W | X | Y |  Z
-------------------------
 a | b | c | 1 | 6 | 8.3
 a | b | c | 1 | 4 | 3.7
 a | b | f | 3 | 4 | 2.6
 a | b | f | 3 | 2 | 6.0
 a | e | c | 1 | 0 | 3.5
 a | e | c | 1 | 5 | 8.8
 d | b | f | 1 | 0 | 3.5
 d | b | f | 1 | 3 | 2.3
 d | e | c | 2 | 6 | 2.2
 d | e | c | 2 | 4 | 3.3
 d | e | f | 0 | 7 | 5.0
 d | e | f | 0 | 6 | 3.6
```

I can produce a second table `B` by grouping the rows of `A` by columns `U`, `V`, and `W`, and computing the average of column Z for each group.

```
         B
-------------------
 U | V | W | Z_avg
-------------------
 a | b | c |  6.0
 a | b | f |  4.3
 a | e | c |  6.2
 d | b | f |  2.9
 d | e | c |  2.7
 d | e | f |  4.3
```

The SQL for this would be something like

```
SELECT U, V, W, AVG(Z) AS Z_avg FROM A GROUP BY U, V, W;
```

But I want the new table to include all the columns of the original table that have a functional dependence on the grouping columns `U`, `V`, and `W`.  In this example there is one such column, namely column `X`.

In other words, I want to generate the table `C` shown below:

```
           C
-----------------------
 U | V | W | X | Z_avg
-----------------------
 a | b | c | 1 |  6.0
 a | b | f | 3 |  4.3
 a | e | c | 1 |  6.2
 d | b | f | 1 |  2.9
 d | e | c | 2 |  2.7
 d | e | f | 0 |  4.3
```

So this problem has two parts, at least conceptually.

1. How to determine which columns are functionally dependent on
    columns `U`, `V`, and `W`?
2. What is the SQL to generate table `C`?

I know how to implement a (say, Python) script that can answer (1), but it is tedious and slow.  (Basically, for each of the candidate columns, in this case `X` and `Y`, the script would collect all of its values for each distinct combination of values in columns `U`, `V`, and `Z`, and then, if each of these sets of values has exactly one element, then the column is functi\onally related to `U`, `V`, and `Z`.)

Likewise, once I have identfied the functionally dependent columns, I can muddle may way through (using temporary tables and what not) to eventually end up with something like table `C` above (thus, effectively solving (2)).

I figure, however, that this task is sufficiently common that there may be standard tools/techniques to carry it out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under the assumptions that you have some columns (say `x` and `y` in your example), that you don't know if they are functionally equivalent or not - and that these columns do not have any `NULL` values (which would complicate things), you can use:

```
SELECT 
    u, v, w,                    -- the grouping columns

    AVG(z) AS z_avg,            -- the non-functionally dependent

    CASE WHEN MIN(x) = MAX(x)   -- a possibly functionally dependent
      THEN MIN(x) ELSE NULL     -- column
    END AS x,

    CASE WHEN MIN(y) = MAX(y)   -- another one
      THEN MIN(y) ELSE NULL
    END AS y
FROM 
    a
GROUP BY 
    u, v, w ;
```

If a column is not functionally dependent (with the current data), it will have at least 2 distinct values, so the `MIN` and `MAX` will be different and the result will be shown as `NULL` in that column, in all rows. You can then remove it from the query.